# Where is "current-folder" i.e "./" in imported functions?

Tags: python, path

Say I have a folder structure

```
main_folder/
├─ sub_folder/
│  ├─ sub_file.py
├─ main_file.py
```

and in `sub_file.py`

```py
def read_data():
    with open("./datafile.txt", "rb") as f:
       data = f.readlines()
   return data
```

where is `"datafile.txt"` then supposed to be located such that any other script, which imports `sub_file.py` can use it i.e where is currentfolder (`./`) when that function is executed?
Furthermore, does the path change if I publish it as a package instead of using it locally?

Comment: A file with a relative path will use whatever the working directory is for the running script. This can be any folder, depending on how the script is executed, and is not relative to the source code. You *can* make the path relative to the source code by using `__file__` to construct a path.

Comment: To elaborate further on what @Grismar wrote, you could, for example, use `os.path.dirname` to get the path from the file like: `os.path.dirname(__file__)`.

Answer (score 0):

The module structure is irrelevant for the addressed issue; the current directory is, what `os.getcwd()` returns, most likely the position, where you started the main script (not the location of that script; as long as you didn't change something by `os.chdir()`). Therefore I suggest, that you change the interface, so `read_data()` receives a file name parameter instead of having to guess later.

Answer (score 0):

The working directory for an application is not inherent in the application, Python scripts are no exception.

For example, consider 'dirlist.py':

```
import os
print(os.listdir())
```

This script prints a list of the files found in the working directory of the script.

When you run `python dirlist.py` from the directory where the script lives, this list will include `'dirlist.py'`. But you can run `python /some/path/dirlist.py` from anywhere and it would list files local to whatever directory you executed that command from.

To make a path relative to the source file, you can use `__file__`:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

print(os.dirlist(Path(__file__).parent))
```